# Angular - How can I refactor *ngIf condition?

Tags: html, angular, refactoring

In my angular code, I have 2 conditions set

`Condition 1` - If weatherService.display is false then show data as Link

`Condition 2` - If weatherService.display is true then do not show data as Link

I see there is code being duplicated for the data that will be shown as link or not.

Is there any way I can optimize this code where `inline-edit-input>` is same?

```
Condition 1 below (Data shown as Link)

  <a [href]="'/nature/'+lp.position+'-'+trial" *ngIf="!weatherService.display"><span>{{runLandText[i]}}</span>
  <inline-edit-input id="runLand_{{i}}" [editable]="weatherService.display && runLandHasNoChildren[i]"
                     (saved)="runLandEdited(i)">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input inlineEditTag matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="runLandEdit[i]">
    </mat-form-field>
  </inline-edit-input>
  </a>

Condition 2 below (Data not shown as Link)


  <span *ngIf="weatherService.display"><span>{{runLandText[i]}}</span>
  <inline-edit-input id="runLand_{{i}}" [editable]="weatherService.display && runLandHasNoChildren[i]"
                     (saved)="runLandEdited(i)">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input inlineEditTag matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="runLandEdit[i]">
    </mat-form-field>   
    </inline-edit-input>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it with `ng-template` and `ng-container`

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-template-wrap?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference

**Ng-Template**

```
<ng-template #inlineEditInput let-i="index">
  <span>{{ runLandText[i] }}</span>

  <inline-edit-input id="runLand_{{i}}" [editable]="weatherService.display && runLandHasNoChildren[i]" (saved)="runLandEdited(i)">
     <mat-form-field>
      <input inlineEditTag matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="runLandEdit[i]">
     </mat-form-field>   
  </inline-edit-input>

</ng-template>
```

**Condition #1**

```
<a [href]="'/nature/'+lp.position+'-'+trial" *ngIf="!weatherService.display">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inlineEditInput"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ index: i }"></ng-container>
</a>
```

**Condition #2**

```
<span *ngIf="weatherService.display">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inlineEditInput"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ index: i }"></ng-container>
</span>
```

**NOTE:**

- **ngTemplateOutlet** renders your ng-template inside your div or in our case we used `ng-container`
- **ngTemplateOutletContext** is your outlet to send data to your `ng-template`